# How to move selected Checkbox to the top of a Checkbox List

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have a Databound Checkbox List and want the selected checkbox item to move to the top of the list.

I've tried searching but all solutions are using html checkbox instead of asp checkbox list

Here is my code for the Checkbox List

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="SBrand" DataValueField="SBrand" AutoPostBack="True" SelectedIndexChanged="gvStock_SelectedIndexChanged" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList_SelectedIndexChanged" OnPageIndexChanging="gvStock_PageIndexChanging" CssClass="checkboxlist">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the CheckBoxList.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Code behind

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the index of the last changed checkbox
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].Split('$').Last());

    //find the correct listitem in the checkboxlist
    ListItem item = CheckBoxList1.Items[index];

    //if the item is already in first position do nothing
    if (index == 0)
        return;

    //remove it from it's current position
    CheckBoxList1.Items.RemoveAt(index);

    //add the listitem at the top
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Insert(0, item);
}
```

This may not work with a `DataSourceID`. So if it does not you have to start binding data to the CheckBoxList from code behind: http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-bind-data-to-checkboxlist-control-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp-1042.aspx

Comment: Nice, works a treat. Thank-you